# Walking by nested states in ui-router without reloading parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my project many organizations. Each organization page contains two parts: header with some organization info, which must load only once, and tabs zone. For tabs i use nested states.

Now question: Can i walk by tabs without reloading organizationCtrl?

router.js

```
$stateProvider
    .state('organization', {
        url: '/organisations/:id',
        templateUrl: 'organization/show.html',
        controller: 'organizationCtrl'
    })
    .state('organization.bio', {
        url: '/bio',
        templateUrl: 'organization/bio.html', 
        controller: 'organizationBioCtrl'
    })
    .state('organization.bio', {
        url: '/gallery',
        templateUrl: 'organization/gallery.html', 
        controller: 'organizationGalleryCtrl'
    });
```

organization/show.html

```
<ul>
    <li ui-sref-active="selected">
        <a ui-sref="organization.bio({ id: organization.id })">Bio</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="selected">
        <a ui-sref="organization.gallery({ id: organization.id })">Gallery</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state change is triggered even if some state-Param is changed. Therefore, until our user will navigate between *bio* and *gallery* of the same organisation `{id}` - the `organizationCtrl` won't be reloaded. In the moment when user will navigate to different organisation `{id}` ... new state change will be triggered and *new* `organiaztionCtrl` will be put in play.

But we can solve it. Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/og66ZwbWk1NNX3qFrExZ?p=preview)

We will split the organisation state into 2 (parent/child). One will be a base/root of the *organisation* without the dependency upon concrete organisation {id}. And that means - will be instantiated only once...

```
.state('base', {
      abstract : true,
      template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
      controller: 'baseCtrl'
    })
    .state('organization', {
      parent : 'base',
      url: '/organisations/:id',
      controller: 'organizationCtrl'
      ...
    })
    .state('organization.bio', {
      url: '/bio',
      ...
    })
    .state('organization.gallery', {
      url: '/gallery',
      ...
    });
```

And now navigating among these links:

```
<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="organization.bio(    { id: 1 })">Orga1 - Bio</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="organization.gallery({ id: 1 })">Orga1 - Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="organization.bio(    { id: 2 })">Orga2 - Bio</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="organization.gallery({ id: 2 })">Orga2 - Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

will not resinstantiate the `baseCtrl` even if the `{id}` will be changed.

```
.controller('baseCtrl', function($scope,...) {
    // pretty stable one
})
.controller('organizationCtrl', function($scope, ...) {
    // changing with id change
})
```

Because the base state is **abstract**, it won't introduce anything into our current model, we only gain the `baseCtrl`...

Please, observe described behaviour in this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/og66ZwbWk1NNX3qFrExZ?p=preview)

Comment: But for some reasons when i navigate between  bio and gallery of the same organisation {id} my organizationCtrl sometimes reloads without any regularity. This is my organizationCtrl:
    `$scope.organization = $resource('/api/organisations/:id.json').get({
        id: $stateParams.organizationId
    });`
which i use in nested controllers.

Comment: I will create a plunker for your, to demonstrate how the solution above works. But one thing is clear: if there is call on `organizationCtrl` it means, that state change was triggered and at least id was changed. Other possiblity is that $state.reload() was called, but this is what I do not expect... will show you in plunker (once plnkr.co is up again)

Comment: Thanks! Just don't understand this phrase `The state change is triggered even if some state-Param is changed.`. I lied a little... In my routing i have additional state parameters like `url: '/gallery?date'` (ignored this) and parameter date was changed. `organizationController` still reloaded but this another problem :) thanks!

Comment: This should be ok, if parameter is belonging to some nested state (gallery). But what I wanted to say: if we will be at /organisations/1/bio', then change to /organisations/2 is enough to trigger state change of the organisation state-level. Providing different params difined in the state === different state is triggered

Comment: I've added a link to plunker where you can observe what we've discussed. Enjoy `ui-router`